# how to save a div in javascript and retrieve it on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working in an online catalog that is composed by a page (let's call it a) with a div `.contenido-catalogo` which gets the products through ajax. Those products have a link to another page (let's call it b). The idea is to save page a's `.contenido-catalogo` in content variable before moving to page b and when the back button of the browser is clicked retrieve the content of the div previously saved. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    var content;

    if (getCookie('foo') == 'bar') {
        $('#contenido-catalogo').html(content);
        setCookie('foo', '');
    };

    $('body').on('click', '.product-link', function() {
        setCookie('foo', 'bar');
        content = $('#contenido-catalogo').html();
    });



    function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {

        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ';';
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: i suggest you use local storage for that.save the content there and retrieve it again if needed. but i think you also need to manually clean the localstorage  to avoid confusion.

Comment: you mean in a cookie right?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage here is a good way of storing in localstorage

Comment: hmm, it doesn't seem to work... do you know if browsers back button triggers `$(document).ready`